# Jython range issue

Tags: python, range, jython

I am writing this program to take a list of input classes along with scores to with them. The goal is to print the class input along with the letter grade associated with the number score input.

However when more than 1 class is put in, it gives me an error saying the sequence index is out of range. Also no matter what score I input it always prints "A" next to the class.

```
course_list = []
score_list = []
grade_list = []
while True:
  course = requestString("Enter a class name or 'q' to quit")
  if  course == 'q':
    break
  else:
    course_list.append(course)
    score = requestString("Enter the class score")
    score_list.append(score)    

if score >= 90:
  grade_list.append(" A")
elif score >= 80:
  grade_list.append(" B")
elif score >= 70:
  grade_list.append(" C")
elif score >= 60:
  grade_list.append(" D")
else:
  grade_list.append(" F")

print "-=Class Scores=-"

final_list = [course_list, grade_list]

for i in range(len(course_list)):
  final = ''
  for j in range(len(final_list)): 
    final += (final_list[j][i])
  print final
```

Comment: The indentation in your code is messed up and hence the output I presume. Your `if` statements checking for score should be in the while loop as per the logic in your code

Comment: Hey so, this course im taking is a CS120 course and the professor insists we use "jython" not python, not sure why it works the way it does but I don't question it lol. Some things are different so I actually got the issue where it only outputted "A" no matter the score to work. it was because I was using requestingString instead of requestInteger so my if and elif statements didn't have an integer to reference so now my only issue is that the "final += (final_list [j] [i]) says its out of range and it only prints 1 class and 1 grade

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with Jython.
All you have to do is to indent the whole `if score [...]`-Block to the same level as the `score_list.append(score)`.

The problem with your code is that this block was outside the `while`-loop, so you extend the `course_list` and the `score_list` until the input is `q`, but only after this is done you take the last score and extend the `grade_list` once.

So the `grade_list` always has the length of 1 (or 0, if no course was given) and the indexing `final_list[j][i]` fails, because it expects the length of the `course_list` to be equal to the length of the `grade_list`.

```
course_list = []
score_list = []
grade_list = []
while True:
  course = requestString("Enter a class name or 'q' to quit")
  if  course == 'q':
    break
  else:
    course_list.append(course)
    score = requestString("Enter the class score")
    score_list.append(score)    
    # this has to happen inside the while-loop:
    if score >= 90:
      grade_list.append(" A")
    elif score >= 80:
      grade_list.append(" B")
    elif score >= 70:
      grade_list.append(" C")
    elif score >= 60:
      grade_list.append(" D")
    else:
      grade_list.append(" F")

print "-=Class Scores=-"

final_list = [course_list, grade_list]

for i in range(len(course_list)):
  final = ''
  for j in range(len(final_list)): 
    final += (final_list[j][i])
  print final
```